# How to make one file compatible with different browsers?

Tags: css

I am making a website, where when i preview it in safari. It turns out exactly as i want it to be. But when i test it out with firefox.

In my page i have a  element that is aligned on the page using

Padding-left and Margin-top. Which works perfectly when i preview it in safari. But when i open the file in firefox. The  element's Margin-top increases by a few pixels.

How do i code my css file so that i can have the same page for different browsers. I have tried looking on the web for a solution, but none of them so far has helped with the problem.

Reply's will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jsteinmann said, check use http://validator.w3.org/ to ensure your page validates. This will take some time to figure out if you are new, but it is an essential step.

If you are having an issue with FireFox, you are probably going to die when you look in IE. Bookmark this link! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

You have a lot to learn and google will help: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=introduction+to+cross+browser+testing&oq=introduction+to+cross+browser+testing&aqs=chrome.0.57.5763&sugexp=chrome,mod=12&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

In future, use stackoverflow for specific questions with code examples. You will find that you get specific answers quite quickly.

Also, don't forget to tick the answer that you find most useful, and also vote some up a level. That's why people spend the time answering your questions.

Enjoy the long road ahead :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Specify all four margin and all four padding values explicitly. That will eliminate the diffferences in the browsers' built-in default stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons why your finding your layouts aren't cross-browser compatible, so it would take a considerable amount of info of the markup and css to make any kind of determination on how to help you code a 100% W3C valid web page.

I would suggest using a css framework like blueprint or 960 for your layouts, so you have less issues in this way.  It's a good way to start and maintain projects, and learn how to create layouts if you choose not to use a framework.

Also, I would suggest testing all of your projects in chrome and firefox first, then safari, simply because of the amount of users that use those two browsers compared to safari.  I would also say, if it looks good in chrome, it will probably look good in safari and firefox, but it's always worth testing.

Comment: I really new to web coding, and yes i should have tested it with firefox and chrome first. But i tried one way of code, where i could keep the safari code in tact. While i could change something in firefox, problem with that was i could make some minor changes (i could add a background-color to the container, and it wouldn't show up in safari). That was a hint that it worked, but i couldn't change the position of the container, even with changing the value of Margin-top, why is that?

Comment: We all started at some point, welcome to the community.  I don't recommend using browser specific code to resolve your issues, and even though IE does support this, you really want to avoid this.  I really recommend checking out a css framework.  It will really help you create a solid pattern of code for your project that is reuseable and with less issues.